# Get new Uri from a moved file

Tags: java, android, uri

I'm doing an image picker in Android. I pick some photos from gallery and after I move those photos to another directory. When I pick those photos I get all information about them (Uris, realPath, if is portrait or not...), now, when I move these photos to another directory I suppose the uri will be changed, right? How can I get the new Uri? I know that will be something like that, but I'm not sure because I don't understand the whole code.
I don't know when I have the Uri's photos moved how to get the new ones. Thanks

```
 protected ArrayList<Image> doInBackground(@NonNull Void... voids) {
        ArrayList images = new ArrayList();
        Cursor imageCursor = null;

        try {
            String[] e = new String[]{"_id", "_data", "date_added", "height", "width"};
            String orderBy = "date_added DESC";
            imageCursor = GalleryActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, e, (String)null, (String[])null, "date_added DESC");

            while(imageCursor.moveToNext()) {
                long _id = imageCursor.getLong(imageCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                int height = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex("height"));
                int width = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex("width"));
                String imagePath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(_id));
                Image image = new Image(_id, uri, imagePath, height > width);
                images.add(image);
            }
        } catch (Exception var16) {
            var16.printStackTrace();
            this.error = var16.toString();
        } finally {
            if(imageCursor != null && !imageCursor.isClosed()) {
                imageCursor.close();
            }

        }

        return images;
    }
```

Comment: There is no code that picks images. There is no code that moves files.

Comment: I know. There is code to get the new data from the moved files. But i don't know how to use properly

Comment: `There is code to get the new data from the moved files. ` Dont think so.